# why is the js equality operator giving me different answers?

Tags: javascript

Even though `newArray.join("")` and `x.toUpperCase()` evaluate to the same string `'MADAM'`, `newArray.join("") === x.toUpperCase()` doesn't return true.

Can someone help me understand why that's the case.

Disclaimer: Function is not designed for one-letter words.

```js
function isPalindrome(x) {
  a=x.toUpperCase().split("")
  if (a.length===1) {
    return a
  }else {
    newArray=[a.pop()]
    newArray=newArray.concat(isPalindrome(a.join("")))
  }
  return newArray.join("")
}

console.log('newArray.join(\'\'):', isPalindrome("Madam"));

function isPalindrome(x) {
  a=x.toUpperCase().split("")
  if (a.length===1) {
    return a
  }else {
    newArray=[a.pop()]
    newArray=newArray.concat(isPalindrome(a.join("")))
  }
  return x.toUpperCase()
}

console.log('x.toUpperCase():', isPalindrome("Madam"));
```

However:

```js
function isPalindrome(x) {
  a=x.toUpperCase().split("")
  if (a.length===1) {
    return a
  }else {
    newArray=[a.pop()]
    newArray=newArray.concat(isPalindrome(a.join("")))
  }
  return (newArray.join("") === x.toUpperCase())
}

console.log('===', isPalindrome("Madam"));
```

I already tested the strict equality expression and found it to work in the example below.

```
x="madam"
a=x.toUpperCase().split("")

console.log(a.join("")===x.toUpperCase());//logs true
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Is this your code and you want to make it working? Or is it from somebody else and you are trying to understand it? Or did you understand it, saw that it is horrible, and want to know how to do it properly?

Comment: function isPalindrome(str) {
 return str.split('').reverse().join('') === str;
}

Comment: This function is way too complicated than it could be...

Comment: "*Function is not designed for one-letter words*" - that's not just a potential flaw, that's a *definite* flaw.

Comment: @Bergi , it's my code and I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, I'm trying to use only recursion to solve the problem.

Comment: @RasNewton Then first decide whether your function should return a boolean or an array (or even a string?). If you think you need both, use two separate functions.

Comment: @HaoWu, yes i know it's complicated. I'm just confused as to why it evaluates to the same string in different returns but still evaluates to false.

Comment: @RasNewton It evaluates to the same string *after you changed the function*. Do a `console.log()` of the values before the `return` in the *unaltered* function, and you'll quickly see.

Comment: @Bergi, i need it to return a boolean. "that's not just a potential flaw, that's a definite flaw. " can you explain the effect of this flaw?

Comment: @RasNewton If you expect `isPalindrome` to return a boolean value, then `return a` and `newArray.concat(isPalindrome(…))` don't make sense.

Comment: "Do a console.log() of the values before the return in the unaltered function, and you'll quickly see. – "@Bergi: Wow!! i just did and i'm impressed. that was very insightful. Thanks @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operator is not flawed. It's something in your code.

Look at this line:

```
newArray = newArray.concat(isPalindrome(a.join("")));
```

When your function returns the string in either `newArray.join('')` case or `x.toUpperCase()` case, they return the same values. So far, so good.

But when your function returns `newArray.join('') === x.toUpperCase()`, it becomes a boolean.

Meaning, in the highlighted line above, it will not ever produce the word `'MADAM'`.

See below example for illustration. It is your function, I've only added `console.log` to let you know what values are returned:

```js
function isPalindrome(x) {
  a=x.toUpperCase().split("")
  if (a.length===1) {
    return a
  }else {
    newArray=[a.pop()]
    newArray=newArray.concat(isPalindrome(a.join("")))
  }
  
  console.log('Raw:', newArray);
  console.log('Joined:', newArray.join(''));
  console.log('Comparison:', newArray.join(''), '===', x.toUpperCase());
  
  return (newArray.join("") === x.toUpperCase())
}

isPalindrome('Madam')
```

**Conclusion**

Your current function will not work. You have to use another way to complete this task.

**PS**

Since you are asking about the potential comparison operator flaw, so I am only answering that.

It is not flawed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no flaw in the strict equality comparison operator. Below is a better and more robust solution that handles single-letter words too.

```
function isPalindrome(string) {

  //first remove possibility of difference by different cases
  string=string.toUpperCase()

  //there are some exceptions that need to be taken care of
  //Exceptions
  //single letter words
  if (string.length===1) {
    return true
  }
  //two letter words
  if (string.length===2) {
    if (string[0]===string[1]) {
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }
  //after taking care of exceptions, you can use recursion to complete
  if (string.length>2) {
    if (string[0]!==string.slice(-1)) {
      return false
    }else{
      output=isPalindrome(string.slice(1,-1))
      return output
    }
  }
  return false
}

isPalindrome("maDAm")//evaluates to true
isPalindrome("a")//evaluates to true
isPalindrome("aba")//evaluates to true
isPalindrome("as")//evaluates to false
```